UnityでVRペンを作りたい
Unity 2022.3.20を使用して、Meta Quest 3向けにVRペンを開発しています。ペンを手で掴み、トリガーとグラブボタンを同時に押すと、ペン先からインクを出して空中に絵や文字を描画したいと考えています。
現在の設定:

ペンオブジェクト:

Building Blocksを使用して、手で掴めるように設定しています。
Penオブジェクトに以下のスクリプトをアタッチしています。


手のオブジェクト:

手のオブジェクトにはHandというタグを付けています。


ペン先:

tipという空のGameObjectをペン先として設定しています。



期待する動作:

ペンを手で掴んだ状態で、トリガーとグラブボタンを同時に押すと、tipからインクが出て線を描画する。

実際の問題:

上記の操作を行っても、ペン先からインクが出ず、描画が開始されません。
デバッグしたところ、StartDrawing()やContinueDrawing()が呼び出されていないようです。
isTouchingHandが正しく判定されていない可能性があります。

以下が使用しているスクリプトです。
using UnityEngine;

public class VRPen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tip;
    public Material inkMaterial;
    public float inkWidth = 0.01f;

    private bool isTouchingHand = false;
    private bool isDrawing = false;
    private LineRenderer currentLine;
    private int positionCount = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        // グラブとトリガーボタンの入力を取得
        bool isGripPressed = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis1D.PrimaryHandTrigger) > 0.5f;
        bool isTriggerPressed = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis1D.PrimaryIndexTrigger) > 0.5f;

        // 条件を満たしたら描画を開始または継続
        if (isTouchingHand && isGripPressed && isTriggerPressed)
        {
            if (!isDrawing)
            {
                StartDrawing();
            }
            else
            {
                ContinueDrawing();
            }
        }
        else if (isDrawing)
        {
            StopDrawing();
        }
    }

    void StartDrawing()
    {
        isDrawing = true;
        currentLine = new GameObject("InkLine").AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (inkMaterial != null)
        {
            currentLine.material = inkMaterial;
        }
        else
        {
            Material defaultMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color"));
            defaultMaterial.color = Color.black;
            currentLine.material = defaultMaterial;
        }

        currentLine.startWidth = inkWidth;
        currentLine.endWidth = inkWidth;
        currentLine.positionCount = 0;
        positionCount = 0;
    }

    void ContinueDrawing()
    {
        positionCount++;
        currentLine.positionCount = positionCount;
        currentLine.SetPosition(positionCount - 1, tip.transform.position);
    }

    void StopDrawing()
    {
        isDrawing = false;
        currentLine = null;
        positionCount = 0;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Hand"))
        {
            isTouchingHand = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Hand"))
        {
            isTouchingHand = false;
        }
    }
}

ご助言いただけると大変助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

IsTorrigerの設定がOFFになっていないかをご確認ください
